# Is Matthew 18:20 literally true? Does Jesus possess the divine ability of omnipresence?

Tags: matthew, christology, attributes-of-god

Matthew 18:20 (NIV):

> 20 For where two or three gather in my name, there am I with them.”

Is Jesus literally omnipresent?

Comment: The words state a literal truth. Some believe that truth and they experience it. Some seem to doubt that truth and they do not experience it. Up-voted +1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the statement of Paul (who was NOT omnipresent) in 1 Cor 5:3

> Although I am absent from you in body, I am present with you in
> spirit, ...

Thus, we have several options to understand Matt 18:20 -

1. Jesus is present by His [Holy] Spirit, who is omnipresent
2. The believers are present in the Spirit of Christ just as they were present with the spirit of Paul; that is not literally but having the same mindset as Christ

Of these two option, I prefer the first (but modified by the comments below) because Jesus spent several chapters in John 14-16 telling the disciples that He could NOT be with them in person so would sent the Advocate = the Holy Spirit, to be with them -

- John 14:16 - And I will ask the Father, and he will give you another advocate to help you and be with you forever--
- John 14:26, But the Advocate, the Holy Spirit, whom the Father will send in my name, will teach you all things and will remind you of everything I have said to you.
- John 15:26 - "When the Advocate comes, whom I will send to you from the Father--the Spirit of truth who goes out from the Father--he will testify about me.

However, this is a vexed subject about which there is much valid debate, so we cannot be too dogmatic.  The simplest, most literal understanding is to take both positions literally and conclude that:

- Jesus is present will all of us via His Holy Spirit as promised in John 14:16, 26, 15:26
- Jesus is present personally where "two or three are gathered" (Matt 18:20).

Comment: "Jesus is present by His [Holy] Spirit, who is omnipresent" How does this follow? Jesus says he will send the Advocate. If the HS is everywhere, why does it have to be sent?

Comment: @OneGodtheFather  When you open up a new business location the manager can begin working from that location from day one and may have worked for the company from its conception but there will always be an official start date for a new chapter. The Holy Spirit is sent in His official capacity Acts 2

Answer (score 0):

The passage suggests the opposite - Jesus is not claiming to be [omnipresent](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/omnipresent).

> "Omnipresent, adjective, present **everywhere** at the same time."

Rather, the statement is claiming conditional presence. "Where two or three gather in my name, there am I with them."

If Jesus were claiming omnipresence here, he could say "Where anyone is, there am I with them."

Comment: What about "conditional omnipresence"? Imagine one million groups of 2 or more people each gathering in Jesus' name, then Jesus should be able to be present in those one million places simultaneously. In other words, Jesus can potentially show up in an unlimited amount of places in the universe at the same time, subject to a condition. Would you call that "conditional omnipresence"?

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator I'm not sure about the term 'conditional omnipresence'. Perhaps 'conditional multipresence' is more accurate. Certain Christians believe Jesus is present in the Eucharistic bread and wine, but that bread and wine isn't everywhere. In theory, could this entail omnipresence? Perhaps, but I don't think that's the thrust of the statement, and would require more work to arrive at.

Comment: You’re trying to differentiate between His omnipresence and when He chooses to manifest. Unfortunately your argument falls apart the moment two groups decide to meet simultaneously in two different locations. If He cannot manifest Himself in both locations simultaneously He lied but if He can, then this is proof of omnipresence

Comment: @NihilSineDeo I can talk to 2 people simultaneously on the phone. You can keep adding callers to the call. Does that mean I'm omnipresent?

Comment: @OneGodtheFather - what about one million simultaneous callers?

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator Sure - why couldn't various technologies allow that? But the point is that simultaneous presence doesn't mean omnipresence. Multipresence *could be* from omnipresence, but omnipresence doesn't follow from multipresence.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather: *"Sure - why couldn't various technologies allow that?"* - I forgot to add that those million callers are all calling simultaneously the same person, who has to be able to maintain one million conversations simultaneously. What kind of technology do you have in mind to accomplish that?  *"Multipresence could be from omnipresence, but omnipresence doesn't follow from multipresence."* - fair enough, but at the very least we have to acknowledge that there is scriptural basis for extraordinary multipresence, and besides God, I'm not aware of other beings capable of the same.

Comment: Besides the fact that the text doesn’t say He will be long distance calling using another medium of communication. The Greek ειμι means He is there present. And μεσω specifies that it’s right in their midst, not remotely. You have a choice accept what the text says (which means accepting Jesus is God) or stick to your extraBiblical creed and have insufficient biblical support.

Comment: @NihilSineDeo The point is not that Jesus uses a telephone - of course not. It's that multipresence doesn't equal omnipresence. Given Jesus is describing conditional multipresence, it suggests the opposite - he is not omnipresent.

Comment: The point is that if you can be in one place at the one time there is nothing special. If you can be in two places at the same time then you have to have divine / God qualities. Not even the heavenly hosts can be in two places at the same time. Jesus is saying He can be present WHEREVER there is a group of two or more gathered in HIS Name. That might not be OMNIPRESENCE in the strict sense of the word but it’s certainly more than any other heavenly being can do

Comment: @NihilSineDeo My guess is this has to do with co-inherence. "I will be in you disciples, and you will be in me." (John 14:20) Co-inherence IMO has to do with an abiding spiritual connection, such that when they pray in His name He is then present.

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator "What kind of technology do you have in mind to accomplish that?" The point is not that Jesus is using an advanced technology. The point is that conditional multipresence does not entail omnipresence, and instead suggests the opposite.

Comment: Why guess when you can just accept what is written? *“Jesus answered him, “If anyone loves me, he will keep my word, and my Father will love him, and we will come to him and make our home with him.”
‭‭John‬ ‭14:23‬* Jesus will make His residence in their biological machine called the human body.

Comment: @NihilSineDeo Yes, exactly - co-inherence. But I'm saying it's my guess that Matthew 18:20 is related to this.

Answer (score -1):

Surprise, surprise, but Jesus is not the source of those words: They originate with the Father.

> Believest thou not that I am in the Father, and the Father in me? the
> words that I speak unto you I speak not of myself: but the Father that
> dwelleth in me, he doeth the works.  (John 14:10)
>
> He that loveth me not keepeth not my sayings: and the word which ye
> hear is not mine, but the Father's which sent me.  (John 14:24)

The Father was in Jesus, and speaking through him.  That is the very essence of "Immanuel," which means "God with us."  Because those were the words of the Father, it is easy to understand how they might be true, for the Father is certainly omnipresent.

For further evidence, consider the following verses:

John 1:18 -- No man has seen God at any time.
John 4:24 -- God is a spirit.
Eph. 4:4  -- There is one spirit.
John 17:3 -- The Father is the only true God.

Touching on Paul's teaching as found in 1 Corinthians 5:3, one can observe something important.  Paul's spirit could be present at their meeting even though he was bodily absent.  To speak of the spirit of Paul is, therefore, biblical.  However, to speak of "Paul the Spirit" would be spiritualism, ascribing to the spirit distinct being-hood.  While all flesh has a spirit, that spirit is not a separate being.  To consider it as a separate being is unbiblical, and spiritualistic.

Observe the dictionary definition for "spiritualism":

> **spiritualism** |ˈspiriCHo͞oəˌlizəm|
>  noun
>  1 a system of belief or religious practice based on supposed communication with the
> spirits of the dead, esp. through mediums.
>  2 *Philosophy* the
> doctrine that the spirit exists as distinct from matter, or that
> spirit is the only reality.

Likewise, the Bible never once uses an expression like "God the Spirit" or "Christ the Spirit" or "Jesus the Spirit."  We may see "Spirit of Christ" (Romans 8:9; 1 Peter 1:11), but that spirit is not styled by its own title as if it were a separate being, i.e. the Bible does not reference "Christ the Spirit."  Clearly, to do so would be spiritualism.

Comment: And what you’re implying is that Jesus won’t be present only the Father because apparently only the Father is God and not also Jesus. *“Jesus answered him, “If anyone loves me, he will keep my word, and my Father will love him, **and WE will come to him and make OUR home with him**.”
‭‭John‬ ‭14:23‬* just to top it off previously He said *“Whoever has my commandments and keeps them, he it is who loves me. And he who loves me will be loved by my Father, **and I will love him and manifest MYSELF to him**.””
‭‭John‬ ‭14:21‬*

Comment: @NihilSineDeo  Jesus is able to be in every place only through his representative, the Holy Spirit.  His humanity is not omnipresent.  "Ye have heard how I said unto you, I go away, and come again unto you. If ye loved me, ye would rejoice, because I said, I go unto the Father: for my Father is greater than I." (John 14:28)  If Jesus were omnipresent, he would not have spoken in this manner.

Comment: What you’re not factoring in, is a time stamp. He said that whilst in a human body, of course the Father is greater than He when He has lowered Himself and limited Himself to a human. Not to mention you completely ignored the verses where He claims to personally be present.

Comment: @NihilSineDeo  Read my response above again and you will see that the words Jesus is speaking are not his own.  Naturally, the Father can legitimately claim to be personally present, and Jesus' use of future tense could apply even to the New Earth.  We must be careful not to force Bible texts to say what they do not actually say.

Comment: You are definitely guilty of forcing the text, either negligently, ignorantly or deliberately. The fact that the words were the Fathers doesn’t change the words that say He (Jesus) AND the Father will come and dwell with the believers (plural).